# How to sort records by date?

Tags: php, codeigniter, sorting

I need help in sorting my records by date descending or ascending as long as it is sorted. I search google how to sort it and found some codes but don't know where to put it in my current code..

```
  <div id="bgbp"></div>
   <div id="navi">
      <?php 
        echo anchor('site/booking_page',"New Booking");
        echo anchor('site/view', "Records");
        echo anchor('site/view_inquiries', "Inquiries");
 ?>
   </div>

  <div id="vi">
   <div id = "search_field">
<?php 
    $search_field = array('name'=>"search_field",'placeholder'=>"Search booking : Type the name of guest.");
    echo form_open('site/view');
    echo form_input($search_field);
    echo form_submit('search',"Search");
 ?>
```

```
       <?php 
          $this->table->set_heading("Name","Nationality","Contact Number","Number of Guest","Date of Arrival","Package","Other Request","Delete Record","Edit Record");
          $qry = $this->db->like('name',$search_key)->get('booking');
          if ($qry->num_rows > 0) {
           foreach ($qry->result() as $row) {
$this->table->add_row(anchor('site/print_records/'.$row->id, $row->name, 'target="_blank"'),$row->nationality,$row->contactnum,$row->number_of_guest,$row->date,$row->package,$row->request,anchor('site/delete/'.$row->id, 'Delete'),anchor('site/update/'.$row->id, 'Edit'));
    }
    }
      else{
      echo "No records found!";
     }

       echo $this->table->generate();

        ?>
```

Comment: If you're storing your dates on the database using one of the built-in date/time datatypes, then it's as easy as `ORDER BY mydatefield`.... if you're storing them as VARCHAR, then you shouldn't be

Comment: yes my built in type in my database is date.. but where do i put that ORDER BY mydatefield?

Comment: Is the code posted in the questions what you found online or what you have tried so far? Where do you get your data from? What are you using to get the data from its source to PHP?

Comment: Which framework are you using, Codeigniter? @user3352042

Comment: Always add relevant tags when asking a question. Some may not be aware of the type of framework you are using. I had a feeling that's what it was, but I had to be sure. I added the tag for you. @user3352042

Comment: ok sorry for that.. next time ill try to be more precise..thanks!

Comment: *No problemo,* and you're welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If my wild guess is correct, you are using something like [Active Record](http://www.phpactiverecord.org/), which should provide you with an [`order_by`](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html) method.

Something like this should therefore do the trick:

```
$this->db->like('name', $search_key)->order_by('bla')->get('booking');
```